# Return multiple coloumns from two diffrent tables using Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

HI here is my Linq to Sql code that returns list of product names from table Product..But I also want to select SellDateTime coloumn from table sale..Please Help

```
var result = ( from p in db.Products
                                 where
                                     (
                                         from s in db.SaleDetails
                                         join se in db.Sales
                                             on s.SaleId equals se.Id
                                         where
                                             (
                                                 from s2 in db.Sales
                                                 where s2.CustomerId == customerId
                                                 select s2.Id
                                             ).Contains(s.SaleId)
                                         select s.ProductId
                                     ).Contains(p.Id)
                                     select p.Name
                             ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var result = ( from p in db.Products
                    join s in db.SaleDetails
                        on p.Id equals s.ProductId
                    join se in db.Sales
                        on s.SaleId equals se.Id 
                    where se.CustomerId==customerId
                    select new 
                    {
                        p.Name,
                        se.SellDateTime
                    }
                 ).ToList();
```